# nvcc not found, despite being on path

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I just installed `CUDA 8.0` on `macOS` using the nvidia installer. It was installed at `/Developer/NVIDIA..` and as such I prepended my `PATH` with `export PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0.61/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}`.

For some reason, it can't find `nvcc` (or the other binaries for that matter), despite the path being set and permissions seemingly okay.

`~$ echo $PATH
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA8.0.61/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Library/TeX/texbin
~$ nvcc
-bash: nvcc: command not found`

Any ideas why this would be the case?

Comment: Have you actually looked in that path to see of it exists, and whether nvcc is there?

Comment: what is the result of running `ls /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA8.0.61/bin` ?  If you followed the [install instructions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-mac-os-x/index.html#install) it doesn't look to me like that is the correct path.  The install instructions suggest something like this:  `export PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0.61/bin ...`  You appear to be missing a `-` after `CUDA`

Comment: oh wow thanks @RobertCrovella, i copy pasted the instructions, but they didn't use wrap the path in `" "` so the hyphen was lost. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas why this would be the case?

Because this is not the correct path:

```
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA8.0.61/bin
```

As indicated in the [install guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-mac-os-x/index.html#install), the correct path is:

```
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0.61/bin
                      ^
```

Note the dash at the indicated location.